# Unchecked assignments RealmResults

Tags: java, android, realm

Im getting this following warning in my code.
 `Unchecked assignment: 'io.realm.RealmResults' to 'io.realm.RealmResults<com.mycompany.app.delivery.Models.Profile>'`

I have this method in `DBManager`

```
protected RealmResults getProfileDataByStaffId(String staffId){
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        final RealmResults<Profile> profile = realm.where(Profile.class).equalTo("staffId", staffId).findAll();
        return profile;
    }
```

and in my Activity im calling method like this

```
DBManager dbManager = new DBManager();
RealmResults<Profile> results = dbManager.getProfileDataByStaffId(staffId);
```

im getting warning in this `dbManager.getProfileDataByStaffId(staffId);` part.

seems to be everything is fine. but not sure why im getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare the same return type of the function as it really is:

```
protected RealmResults<Profile> getProfileDataByStaffId(String staffId)
```

This is not error, this is a warning of `Android Lint`, as it does not correctly match the types. In this case it could be ignored, however it is a good practise to eliminate such warnings.